# Expire date coming wrong

Tags: php

Good Day

I am selecting date from datepicker and after adding one year, it generates expire date, which is correct
But when I echo it shows Active on wrong date and expired on wrong date like on 27-04-2021 its expiry will be in 27-04-2022 but it shows active, it should show expired
Please help

Code Below

```
<?php
$status = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
//$trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");echo '<br />';
$approvedate =$_POST['approvedate'];echo '<br />';
$today =date("d-m-Y");echo '<br />';
$expiredate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($approvedate)));

if($today>$expiredate)
{
echo 'Expired';}
else
{
echo 'Active';}




}
?>
```

$approvedate  is a value from datepicker.

Comment: When you compare dates like that, it compares it as strings, and `03-10-2022` is not greater than `27-04-2022`. 0 is less than 2. Use a more sane format, such as `Y-m-d`.

Comment: @aynber Worked Now Grreat Help Thanks a lot